# How to get the status of notification permission from the device settings via Unity Firebase SDK?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to get the status of user's notification permission from the device settings via Unity Firebase SDK?

I integrated firebase cloud messaging and it's working great. Now I need to show a text to the user of my app stating "you should enable the  notifications in settings app" if the user didn't give the notification permission earlier.